# Does duty cycle have effect on sending pulse train properly for long distances

Tags: pulse

A system will use coaxial cables to convey pulses to trigger remote systems. The cable lengths might vary up to 100m. In that case, if the duty cycle of a 30Hz fixed pulse train is too low like %0.05 (less than 20us), is there any possible benefits to stretch the duty cycle to around 50%? Is there any relation?

Answer (score 2):

Most coax cables quite easily carry data in the mega bits per second range and at distances exceeding 100 metres. Each bit would be no more than 1 us wide so I think you would find it hard to choose a coax cable that wouldn't be suitable.

If your "system" is susceptible to signal reflections you might wish to choose a design that used terminating resistors.

Answer (score 1):

20 µS is a "long" time for a properly terminated decent coax cable over 100 m.  There should be no problem unless there is something *very* unusual going on that you're not telling us about.